# Is it possible to appliy gradient descent if the gradient is not linear in x

Tags: mathematical-statistics, optimization, svm

I am trying to implement a SVM classifier. The problem is equivalen to finding the $\{\alpha\}$ that maximizes the following loss function:
$$
\operatorname{max}\limits_{\alpha}L(\alpha)=\sum_{i=1}^{N} \alpha_{i}-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{j=1}^{N} \alpha_{i} \alpha_{j} y^{(i)} y^{(j)} \mathbf{x}^{(i)^{\top}} \mathbf{x}^{(j)}
$$

Whose gradient is:

$$\nabla L(\alpha)=(1)^{T}-\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
y_{1} y_{1} x_{1}\cdot x_{1} & \cdots & y_{1} y_{N} x_{1}\cdot x_{N} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
y_{N} y_{1} x_{N}\cdot x_{1} & \cdots & y_{N} y_{N} x_{N}\cdot x_{N}
\end{array}\right] \alpha$$

The problem is that the gradient depend on the dot product of x. How can I implement a gradient ascent given that gradient?

Comment: Off the top of my head, finding a solution for the SVM classifier using the Lagrangian dual formulation you have specified generally invites solution using quadratic programming.This approach is essentially solving a constrained quadratic programming problem.  From what I've seen, the Lagrangian dual formulation tends not to invite solution using (sub)-gradient descent methods. If you want to go down the latter route, you will need to set-up your problem so as to do unconstrained empirical loss minimisation with a penalty term consisting of the norm of the classifier.

Comment: You will then need to compute the (sub)gradient of this objective function and proceed from there. Will write-up more clearly and direct you to some references a little later.

Comment: Here is a paper about an SVM solver called Pegasos - it was what I had in mind when I wrote the above comments. Can you see how the way they use (sub)-gradient descent is distinct from the approach you have opted for?

https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~shais/papers/ShalevSiSrCo10.pdf